# jQuery Datatables - Return only first 5 rows in table from search

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, datatables

I know I can filter the rows by:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
//#column3_search is a <input type="text"> element
$('#column3_search').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.columns( 3 ).search( this.value ).draw();
});
```

How do i return for example only the first 3 results out of this search?

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `pageLength`

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 3
} );
```

or try adding `page.len(3)` before `.draw()` (doc: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len())

```
table.columns( 3 ).search( this.value ).page.len(3).draw();
```

**Solution with a custom filtering** (as in https://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)

> DataTables provide an API method to add your own search functions,
>   `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search`. This is an array of functions (push your
>   own onto it) which will will be run at table draw time to see if a
>   particular row should be included or not.

Use

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter) {
      var maxIndex = 4;
      if (counter <= maxIndex) {
        return (true);
      }
      return false;
    }
  );
```

here I set `maxIndex = 4` to include only the first 5 rows of the search results.

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/nk0m2ekv/

Comment: This will jst add a paginator and place other rows in other pages. but its a good start